# Can I have align <li> into left and right when it has an absolute position <li>

Tags: html, css

I am having a simple `HTML` list and it always would have an even number of items as below:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
  <li></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 8</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to get this list into the center of the page. Above `:empty` li have a fixed width and it is always position on center of the page.

My question is I need to align before and after `<li>`s of the `:empty` `<li>` as attached image below. (In this case, first four `<li>` to right and last four `<li>` to left to the `:empty` item). Exept `:empty` all other `<li>` have variable width.

[image]

**This is my `CSS`:**

```
ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

ul > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

ul > li:empty {
  width: 10em;
  background: #e04c4c;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.left.last {
  margin-right: 5em;
}

.right.first {
  margin-left: 5em;
}
```

Its working for me, if I have fixed width `<li>`, But here I can't use fixed width.

Can anybody tell me is there any other way to get my desired output?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I find that it helps to rethink the structure of your html. Since the fixed width empty space needs to be in the center of the screen you were right to have it absolutely positioned. However, translating it is problematic because other elements do not respect a translated element. Instead we can just move it right by `2em` since we know that's half of the fixed width element.

Next we can position the two sides on either side of the empty space. The left side gets translated by 100% of its own width. And the right side gets translated by 4em (the width of the empty space).

Finally some fun pseudo styling for the vertical bars in the image just in case you needed it. Hope that helps!

```css
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  ul > li:not(:last-child):after {
    content: "|";
    padding: 0.5em;
  }

  .empty-space {
    position: absolute;
    right: calc(50% - 2em); /* translate won't work here but we know it's fixed width */
    width: 4em;
    height: 2em;
    background-color: gray;
  }

  .list-left, .list-right {
    position: absolute;
    height: 2em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }



  .list-left {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

  .list-right {
    transform: translateX(4em);
  }
  
  /* Not necassary. Just to confirm that it is indeed in the center */
  .page-center {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%
  }
```

```html
<div class="empty-space">
  <ul class="list-left">
     <li><a href="">Item 1 is longer</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-right">
     <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Item 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- Not necassary. Just to confrim that it is indeed in the center -->
<div class="page-center"></div>
```